# What is the spelling of the sound one makes to caution, admonish or direct another (eh ehh)?

Tags: single-word-requests

It’s the sound one may make while wagging a finger at another person.

Comment: usually, "tsk" , but could have otrher spellings

Comment: I think he means something else (that was my first thought, too, though).

Comment: If it were in dialogue, I would easily parse "tsk, tsk" as you describe. In fact, Oxford Living Dictionaries and Merriam-Webster both show it is a valid word: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tsk-tsk "Used to express disapproval or annoyance."

Comment: I associate _tsk tsk_ however it sounds in actual production with shaking one's head sideways.

Comment: "Tut tut" is the traditional British way of spelling those reproachful clicks of the tongue. On reflection, though, the questioner probably means something more like jxh's "Uh-uh".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are wanting ***uh-uh***:

> —used to indicate negation
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uh-uh)</sub>

I associate ***eh*** with rhetorical questions, but the dictionary says it can be applied more generally.

> —used to ask for confirmation or repetition or to express inquiry
>   —used especially in Canadian English in anticipation of the listener's or reader's agreement
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eh)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It's more the two- or three-note melody than pronunciation, which is something like two eighth notes and a quarter note with a rising, then falling tone on the final syllable:

> nya ah ah
>
> na ah ah

The *ny* or *n* suggest negation,

or, infamously in this scene from the first [*Jurrassic Park*](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=K3PrSj9XEu4), where the computer geek blocks all systems and says

> ah, ah, ah

with the usual melody and the requisite finger wagging, exaggerated into a forearm motion.